# Meteor loginWithFacebook : Error in OAuth Server

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-oauth

loginWithFacebook has stopped working for me. 
Even the previous version of the code. 
The plain code with just {{> loginButtons}} when run, on click connects to facebook, but on return waits very long for localhost and throws back this error after some time.

```
W20150123-21:16:55.743(5.5) (oauth_server.js:398) Error in OAuth Server: Failed to complete OAuth handshake with Facebook. connect ETIMEDOUT
```

I'm running my app inside a corporate network with proxy. Facebook is accessible and i', able to login other apps like soundclound with login via facebook.

When i'm connecting via other source (mobile data) i'm able to do a login. Any suggestion on how to find root cause ?

Comment: Is the server on the same terminal as where you access Facebook? You mention the corporate infra, just checking.

Comment: yeah. tried that. it didn't work.

Comment: Is the Meteor app able to use the proxy to begin the OAuth flow to facebook, or is it just your browser that is set up to do this? You can test this by doing a request from within your Meteor app using the `http` package

Comment: yes. when i'm  not logged in, it takes me to facebook login page, where i can enter my credentials. while returning it gets stuck.

Comment: @kanadenipun This but this is your web browser, your meteor app also needs to be able to communicate through your proxy, this is probably why the OAuth handshake fails, the request is made from the meteor app not the browser

Comment: Does meteor require any other port to be opened for oauth ? I think this should not be the case.